# How to manage a wordpress website with Git?

Tags: wordpress, git, paas

As `wordpress` requires regular updates for it's plugins, how to manage a `wordpress` git repository so to deploy a website on Paas servers like `IBM Bluewmix` ?

Comment: Try this workflow: http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Capistrano with WordPress for deployment.

The plugins and themes you are coding on would I put under git.

Some informations:

https://github.com/herrkris/wordpress-capistrano

[Capistrano 3 deploy WordPress with GIT available in release dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506052/capistrano-3-deploy-wordpress-with-git-available-in-release-dir)

http://robert-reiz.com/2014/04/27/deployment-with-capistrano-3/

Comment: Thanks! will surely try it out.

Comment: You're welcome. It would be nice if you can accept my answer, thanks.